# Implementing a tab/task bar purely in JS/html/css

Tags: javascript, css, html, tabs

Im trying to create a task bar made up of tabs(not browser tabs) running in one window.

I need to keep track of whats going on in each of these tabs, have separate breadcrumbs per tab.(For this i was thinking maybe of using a cookie in the browser per tab to save the depth, i.e. how many liks youve clicked into something and the links so you can travel back)

The tabs need to be closable and sortable, different skins, some with text some with only icons.

All of this needs to be kept in one window - those are the requirements.

Looking for a few tips, advice on doing this. Also of any known plugins - ive looked at jquery ui - im thinking for this because its so custom to the requirements its more suitable to write one.

Comment: so you want something like the jqGrid demo site? http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like [50+ Nice Clean CSS Tab-Based Navigation Scripts](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/) or if you wanted back and froth support you could use a [modified version of this](http://nontroppo.org/test/tab1.html).